# Is there any way to change the location of the left side toolbar (show/hide with T)

Tags: interface

I'm getting into sculpting, and I don't like that brushes are on the left side (I'm left handed and find it weird), I would like them to be on the right side. I haven't seen any post on that in google so I really have no clue. Any tips on that?

NB : I know that you can bring up the menu with  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> but if I can change the toolbar's position I'd like it more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Edit > Preferences and under 'Display', check the 'Developer Extras' checkbox and close the dialog. If you now use F3 to search and type in 'flip' you'll see an option called 'screen.region_flip * Flip Region'.
Click that and your toolbar will magically appear on the right of the window!

Comment: I should have added that you need to hover the mouse over the toolbar that you want to move before using the F3 key. - It works in layout view too.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I wish I could save the brushes location now that it's on the right side, for some reason it resets everytime I reopen Blender but it's fine as it takes 2 seconds to setup!

Comment: Nevermind I forgot it's Default > Save and not in user preferences to save the workspace!

Comment: Good! Glad to help!

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit of a workaround, but as overlays are *per viewport*, you can split the view and disable the header and overlays on the right like so:

[image]

Then drag the left viewport over till the <kbd>T</kbd> menu is positioned correctly.

[image]

Save this as your sculpting workspace, and you should be all set.

Comment: Neat workaround indeed, I'll remember this solution if I need something specific like this!

Answer (score 3):

[image: Flip Operator]

You can use the Flip to Bottom (or just flip header) operator - first assigning a hotkey then using when hovering over the toolbar. The hotkey for this is usually F5 from the 2.79 days.